# Cross-compilation error | '_Float128' does not name a type; did you mean '_Float32x'?

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, arm64

I am facing an issue while cross-compiling an application using cmake. I am using external Buildroot based SDK for cross-compilation for one of the projects. It's a "aarch64" based and I have other SDK which are "arm" based and they compile without any errors.

Compilation is successful using `cmake ../. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[...]/ToolchainFile.cmake`
And it fetches correct path from SDK for C and CXX compilers. But when I run `make` I get below errors:

```
In file included from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/wchar.h:30,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/cwchar:44,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/bits/char_traits.h:40,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/string:40,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/include/Action.hpp:27,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/src/Action.cpp:26:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/floatn.h:87:9: error: '__float128' does not name a type; did you mean '__cfloat128'?
   87 | typedef __float128 _Float128;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~
      |         __cfloat128
In file included from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/cwchar:44,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/bits/char_traits.h:40,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/string:40,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/include/Action.hpp:27,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/src/Action.cpp:26:
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/wchar.h:406:8: error: '_Float128' does not name a type; did you mean '_Float32x'?
  406 | extern _Float128 wcstof128 (const wchar_t *__restrict __nptr,
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
      |        _Float32x
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/wchar.h:523:8: error: '_Float128' does not name a type; did you mean '_Float32x'?
  523 | extern _Float128 wcstof128_l (const wchar_t *__restrict __nptr,
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
      |        _Float32x
In file included from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/cstdlib:75,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/bits/basic_string.h:6496,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/string:55,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/include/Action.hpp:27,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/src/Action.cpp:26:
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:152:8: error: '_Float128' does not name a type; did you mean '_Float32x'?
  152 | extern _Float128 strtof128 (const char *__restrict __nptr,
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
      |        _Float32x
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:245:4: error: '_Float128' has not been declared
  245 |    _Float128 __f)
      |    ^~~~~~~~~
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:330:8: error: '_Float128' does not name a type; did you mean '_Float32x'?
  330 | extern _Float128 strtof128_l (const char *__restrict __nptr,
      |        ^~~~~~~~~
      |        _Float32x
In file included from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/cstdlib:75,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/bits/basic_string.h:6496,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/string:55,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/include/Action.hpp:27,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/src/Action.cpp:26:
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:935:5: error: expected initializer before '__attr_access'
  935 |     __attr_access ((__read_only__, 2));
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:940:3: error: expected initializer before '__attr_access'
  940 |   __attr_access ((__write_only__, 1, 3)) __attr_access ((__read_only__, 2));
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdlib.h:994:30: error: expected initializer before '__attr_access'
  994 |      __THROW __nonnull ((2)) __attr_access ((__write_only__, 2, 3));
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/bits/basic_string.h:6496,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/string:55,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/include/Action.hpp:27,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/src/Action.cpp:26:
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/cstdlib:154:11: error: '::mbstowcs' has not been declared
  154 |   using ::mbstowcs;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/cstdlib:171:11: error: '::wcstombs' has not been declared
  171 |   using ::wcstombs;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/cstdio:42,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/bits/basic_string.h:6496,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/string:55,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/include/Action.hpp:27,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/src/Action.cpp:26:
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdio.h:569:12: error: expected initializer before '__attr_access'
  569 |      __wur __attr_access ((__write_only__, 1, 2));
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/stdio.h:593:5: error: expected initializer before '__attr_access'
  593 |     __attr_access ((__write_only__, 1, 2));
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/bits/basic_string.h:6496,
                 from /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/string:55,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/include/Action.hpp:27,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/src/Action.cpp:26:
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/cstdio:108:11: error: '::fgets' has not been declared
  108 |   using ::fgets;
      |           ^~~~~
In file included from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/include/Action.hpp:29,
                 from /root/sources/aarch64/aws-iot-client/lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/src/Action.cpp:26:
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/memory: In function 'void* std::align(std::size_t, std::size_t, void*&, std::size_t&)':
/opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/opt/ext-toolchain/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.4.0/memory:121:58: error: cast from 'void*' to 'uintptr_t' {aka 'unsigned int'} loses precision [-fpermissive]
  121 |   const auto __intptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(__ptr);
      |                                                          ^
make[2]: *** [lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/CMakeFiles/aws-iot-sdk-cpp.dir/build.make:66: lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/CMakeFiles/aws-iot-sdk-cpp.dir/src/Action.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:341: lib/aws-iot-device-sdk-cpp/CMakeFiles/aws-iot-sdk-cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:133: all] Error 2
```

I don't understand what is the reason for this error whereas it builds successfully for "arm" SDK.

```
ToolchainFile.cmake
```

```
# General CMAKE cross compile settings
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# Specify Sysroot path
SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/)

# Specify path to find filesystem items
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/)

# Search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# Search for libraries and headers in the target directories
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

# Specify toolchain directory
SET(TOOLCHAIN_DIR /opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/bin/)

# Specify cross compilation target
SET(TARGET_CROSS aarch64-linux-)

# Set compilers
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/${TARGET_CROSS}g++)

# Set linker
SET(CMAKE_LINKER ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/${TARGET_CROSS}ld)

# Set compiler flags
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${COMMON_FLAGS} -std=c++11)

# Set archiving tool
SET(CMAKE_AR ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/${TARGET_CROSS}ar CACHE FILEPATH "Archiver")

# Set randomizing tool for static libraries
SET(CMAKE_RANLIB ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/${TARGET_CROSS}ranlib)

# Set strip tool
SET(CMAKE_STRIP ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/${TARGET_CROSS}strip)

# Set objdump tool
SET(CMAKE_OBJDUMP ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/${TARGET_CROSS}objdump)

# Set objcopy tool
SET(CMAKE_OBJCOPY ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/${TARGET_CROSS}objcopy)

# Set nm tool
SET(CMAKE_NM ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/${TARGET_CROSS}nm)

# Set THREADS_PTHREAD_ARG for testing threading
SET(THREADS_PTHREAD_ARG "2" CACHE STRING "Forcibly set by ToolchainFile.cmake." FORCE)
```

In the `CMakeCache.txt` all the paths are fetched from SDK and nothing from build system

Can anyone please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

P.S: I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Please let me know if any info is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

`x86_64-linux-gnu` is something you would not hope to see in an aarch64 build, yet you use `x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/floatn.h`

You'll need to figure out exactly how that sneaks in. Where exactly does your SDK break out of its directories and use a non-SDK header?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to figure out that. Any idea where could be the potential source of mistake? Or how can I check it?

Comment: @Preeti: Start with the top of the error message, `opt/sdk_mmia53.e2c-demo.640/aarch64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/wchar.h:30`. Does that line reference `floatn.h` ?